# Does apple rejects the application that reads the call history of iphone using FMDB database in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I am using FMDB database to read the call history of the iphone.I need to know whether apple rejects my application if I go under this process.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is not only user's private information but also phone internal I guess Apple will reject the app. You are [not supposed to access files outside your app sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) (see point 2.6 of the linked App Store guidelines) except with the classes that Apple has provided (e.g. for accessing the phone book).